# Javascript and JSON (DOM)

Tags: javascript, json, dom

So I have this kind of website where it is kinda online shop of shoes where you have a JSON file where I have to display this in HTML using javascript. So the JSON file looks like this:

```
[

    {
       "name": "DKNY",

       "category": "Stilettos",

       "location": "Texas",
    },

    {
       "name": "Prada",

       "category": "Wedge",

       "location": "Texas",
    },

    {
       "name": "Jimmy Choo",

       "category": "Stilettos",

       "location": "Melbourne",
    },
]
```

and there is this HTML file with the categories

Wedge

Stilettos

where once you click those categories (like for example you click Stilettos) in HTML for Stilettos, it will display all the categories and data written on json file like "stilettos" then will display the name of shoes and its location. Is there any way you could do this? into JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Store all your data in variable, let's say:

```
var allShoes = ... //your JSON data
```

then add function for filter your shoes by category, like this:

```
function filterShoesByCategory(category) {
    return allShoes.filter(shoe => shoe.category === category); // returns filtered array - original array is kept unchanged
}
```

In addition you need some logic for update your DOM. It depends if you're using pure JS, jQuery or some framework.

Answer (score -1):

You have to improve this code to fit your needs, but this is the concept you have to use.

```js
var shoes = [{
    "name": "DKNY",

    "category": "Stilettos",

    "location": "Texas",
  },

  {
    "name": "Prada",

    "category": "Wedge",

    "location": "Texas",
  },

  {
    "name": "Jimmy Choo",

    "category": "Stilettos",

    "location": "Melbourne",
  },
];

async function show(cat) {
  if (!shoes) { //check if shoes are already loaded
    var response = await fetch("shoes.json"); //fetch the file
    shoes = await response.json(); //convert the file to JSON
  }
  var list = document.getElementById("list"); //get the output element
  list.innerHTML = ""; //clear the output element
  var selected = shoes.filter(s => s.category && s.category === cat);
  //filter the shoes to only contain elements with the right category
  selected.forEach(s => { //iterate over the shoes to display them
    list.innerHTML += "<h4>" + s.name + "</h4>";
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="show('Stilettos')">Stilettos</button><button onclick="show('Wedge')">Wedge</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: how do you do it if you are reading from an external local json file? thank you

Comment: I included the loading part in my edit. To use it just remove the JSON object after `var shoes`

Comment: how about if you are to link it on a <nav> inside <ul><li><a href="#">Stilletos</a></li><ul>?

Comment: I think you should be the one doing the coding we are just here to answer your questions or give you advice in problems

Comment: highly appreciated